# ZK Hide the Input Field of Datebox

Tags: zk, datebox, zul

How can I hide the input field of Datebox?
I've tried to set the width to "0px", but the input field still visible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you just want to show the calendar icon?

```css
        .z-datebox-input{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
```

You can add `width:20px` to make it smaller.